# Android Studio - некорректная работа каретки!

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Как только не пробовал - каретка возвращается обратно в это состояние: Ноутбук, Win 10. версии Android Studio устанавливал и последние, и предыдущие. <kbd>Insert</kbd> помогает лишь на текущей вкладке проекта и при перезапуске среды всё возвращается. Стандартные комбинации клавиш не работают, даже если менять в настройках. <kbd>Insert</kbd> помогает, но комбинации клавиш всё равно не работают и при нажатии комбинации каретка возвращается в исходное состояние.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В других средах разработки всё хорошо, такой проблемы нет. При таком режиме каретки печатать тоже не получается - звучит звук, как при конфликте с другой открытой программе/окне. Как видите на скрине ниже - настройки сочетаний пытался менять, но это ничего не дало. Настройки клавиш в Android Studio и Intellij Idea одинаковые. Кэш чистил, Clean и Rebuild делал.

File->Settings->Editor->General->Appearance чекбокс Use block care не активен!

Нажата ли клавиша <kbd>scroll lock</kbd> проверил на экранной клавиатуре - не нажата. Прошу помощи! Так работать невозможно!

Answer (score 0):

Отключи плагин IdeaVim или Vlang (менее вероятно) и всё получится с настройками.